# Can't exit from docker-compose logs -f [container name]

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, exit

I can successfully follow the logs of a container by entering `docker-compose -f [containerName]` (where containerName is the name of the docker container I want to follow.
Once I'm following the logs, though, I'm unable to exit by pressing `control + c`, `control + z` , `q`, `bye` or any of the normal exit commands. 
The log just continues

Comment: You could always open up a second terminal and search for the process and send it a SIGINT (kill -2)

Comment: @Mike that's true, but it happens frequently enough that I would like to see if there is a solution that's a little more elegant.

Comment: May I know on which OS you are facing this Issue?

Comment: @SunilValmiki, Ubuntu

Comment: I'm having this same issue on gcloud's web shell, I thought it might be a web-shell-ism, but your questions leads me to believe it's an issue with docker-compose, since I have this behavior when I run `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> two or three times**, which will usually stop the logging process with:

> `ERRO[0004] got 3 SIGTERM/SIGINTs, forcing shutdown`

As of November 2021, there is still a docker-compose bug that prevents closing the logs when using the `--follow` (`-f`) flag with a single <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

See GitHub project issue: [CTRL-C does not end compose logs -f #8880](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8880)

Comment: Thanks for linking to that issue!
It looks like they attempted to fix it, but it's still showing up, and another issue has been linked to the one you posted.
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8977

Answer (score 18):

`Ctrl+\` sends `SIGQUIT`, which prints out debug information and ends the process.

Comment: This is the one that should be accepted. I was looking for a way for exiting WITHOUT CTRL+C :-)

Answer (score 1):

in a centos machine I use

```
docker-compose logs -f -t
```

to see the logs and

```
control-C
```

to escape from logs. It appears:

> q ^CERROR: Aborting.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of using docker-compose logs -f -t. Just the combination I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

To cover another case, on Amazon Linux 2 server, `Ctrl+C` doesn't close the logs (even clicked multiple times), just prints `^C`.

`Ctrl+\` works well, but outputs the debugging info, which is actually about 100 lines of garbage assuming you don't want to debug:)

And `Ctrl+Z` works just fine.